# Keystore password tampered with

Tags: java, android, sdk, passwords, keystore

I have been uploading my android-app to Google Play for a while now. It has been working flawlessly until last night.

When I try to export my android project I get an error when I am typing in the password to my keystore.

Earlier my debug.keystore-file location was set to my .android folder by default. Now however I have to specifically choose it. Anyway, when I am typing my password (which I have used for eight earlier releases and therefor am 100% sure is correct) I get the following error message:

> "Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect"

How can I fix this?

The only change I am aware of that I have made since my last successful release is that I have updated the Android SDK from version 1.6 to version 1.7. Could this have any effect on the validity of my debug.keystore and its password?

I usually find my answers by googling, but in this case I still do not find the solution after several hours of search. Please help me. I really want to put up my new release as soon as possible:)

Comment: did u tried resigning ur application?

Comment: What do you mean by resigning?

Comment: I mean have u tried signing it again using export wizard in manifest?

Comment: you have updated Android SDK or Java SDK?

Comment: @Misha I have several times tried to sign it in Eclipse using File>Export>Export Android Application, and so forth, if that is the wizard you mean?

Comment: @Nagaraj436 As far as I am aware I have only updated the Android SDK

Comment: Current Android SDK version 4.2 and you are saying that updated android to 1.7. Some confusion.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that I upgraded my SDK Platform to the API level 17

Comment: @Nagaraj436: I do not know if the API level of the SDK platform is relevant, but I'm mentioning it since I know that it is a variable that has been changed since my last successful exoprt.

Comment: Problem solved! Turned out I had two keystores and was using the wrong one. Classic mistake:)

Answer (score 0):

Why did you mention `debug.keystore-file`? Have you signed your release with a debug key? Debug keys get recreated when they expire. So maybe that's what happend.
As the [SDK docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) say you have to sign your apk with a release key before uploading to Google Play.